# Unable to make a rake-tasks file and make it work properly

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake

I decided to create a rake tasks for my Sinatra project and not to use the ready ones.

```
#Rakefile

 require 'rake/testtask'
 require 'rake/clean'
 Dir.glob("tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }

#/tasks/seed.rake
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require 'mongoid'
require_relative '../models/user'

namespace :db do
  task :seed do
    puts 'Creating a user....'

    user1 = User.new email: "email1@gmail.com", password: "test123"
    user1.save!

    puts 'User has been created.'
  end
end

#user.rb

require 'bcrypt'
require 'digest/md5'
require 'openssl'

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  #.........

#gemfile (partly)
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', require: 'bcrypt'
```

And I've got the error of "Creating a user....

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `create!' for BCrypt::Password:Class
/home/alex/ruby_projects/service/models/user.rb:47:in `password='"
```

where #47 looks like

```
  def password= pass
    self.hashed_password = BCrypt::Password.create! pass, cost: 10
  end
```

Note that in normal development everything works just **fine**. So I missed to require a file I think.

Your thoughts?

p.s. Even if I put

```
   require 'bcrypt'
    require 'digest/md5'
    require 'openssl
```

to `/tasks/seed.rake` the error remains.

Comment: Where is the `BCrypt::Password.create!` method defined? Looking at the [BCrypt docs](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html), I only see a `.create` method, and no `.create!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using a non-existant method from BCrypt::Password. According to the [docs](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html), there is only a `.create` method and no `.create!` method. Switch to `BCrypt::Password.create` and it should work.

```
def password= pass
  self.hashed_password = BCrypt::Password.create pass, cost: 10
end
```